# Finding the average of an array using c

Tags: c, average

I am new to coding in C and I am trying to get the average of the array but for some reason it is not calculating, it is giving me a result of 0.0.

How can I fix this. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
float grades_average(float grades[7]);
int main() {

 float grades[7]={98.8, 97.9, 99.3, 99.8, 99.6, 99.4, 99.9};
 float average;
 average = grades_average(grades);
 printf("Average is: %.2f",average);


 return 1;
}
float grades_average(float grades[7]){
 int i;
 float sum = 0;
 float average = 0.0;
 /* calculate the sum of grades using for loop*/
    for(i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
       sum = sum + grades[7];
    }
 average = sum/7;

 return average;
}
```

The output is:

```
Average is: 0.00
```

Comment: for 7 items your loop should go from 0 to 6.. Also why are you doing `sum = sum + grades[7];` ? you are summing up 1 item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimum change solution:

```
float grades_average(float grades[7]){
 int i;
 float sum = 0;
 float average = 0.0;
 /* calculate the sum of grades using for loop*/
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
       sum = sum + grades[i];
    }
 average = sum/7.f;

 return average;
}
```

1. Change `for(i = 0; i <= 7; i++){` to `for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){`.  Valid indicies for grades are only 0-6.  7 is out of bounds.
2. Change `sum = sum + grades[7];` to `sum = sum + grades[i];`  You need to check each element, not the (beyond) last one over and over.
3. Change `average = sum/7;` to `average = sum/7.f;`  The `.f` ensures no integer division.  That preserves the decimal during division.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here is full code. with 2 changes, Line 20 and Line 23

```
#include <stdio.h>
float grades_average(float grades[7]);
int main() {

 float grades[7]={98.8, 97.9, 99.3, 99.8, 99.6, 99.4, 99.9};
 float average;
 average = grades_average(grades);
 printf("Average is: %.2f",average);


 return 1;
}
float grades_average(float grades[7]){
 int i;
 float sum = 0;
 float average = 0.0;
 /* calculate the sum of grades using for loop*/

   /*Changed here to <7 because i takes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 which are 7 elements, your code is <=7 which takes 0.......7 which are 8 elements */
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){

       /*Changed here to i from 7, your code everytime sums out of bound element, Garbage value since grades[7] does not exist*/
       sum = sum + grades[i];
    }
 average = sum/7;

 return average;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Change `for(i = 0; i <= 7; i++){}` to `for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){}`, because 
     totally you have 7 elements, starting from `0`to`6`.
2. Change `sum = sum + grades[7];` to `sum = sum + grades[i];`, as grades[7] will only have the last value of the array, but you want to add all the values present in the array.

   ## include

   ```
   float grades_average(float grades[7]);
   int main() {

    float grades[7]={98.8, 97.9, 99.3, 99.8, 99.6, 99.4, 99.9};
    float average;
    average = grades_average(grades);
    printf("Average is: %.2f",average);


    return 1;
   }
   float grades_average(float grades[7]){
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    float average = 0.0;
    /* calculate the sum of grades using for loop*/
       for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
          sum = sum + grades[i];
       }
    average = sum/7.f;

    return average;
   }
   ```

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting i in place of 7,

```
 sum = sum + grades[7];
```

like

```
sum = sum + grades[i];
```

and your loop from 0 to 6

Answer (score 0):

In place of using this

```
 sum = sum + grades[7];
```

Use

```
sum = sum + grades[i];
```

Then it will work.